# Transforming Gamma into Chi-squared distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, gamma-distribution

My question is about how to transform a Gamma distrbution in a Chi-squared one. 
I know that $X\sim\Gamma(\frac{\nu}{2},2$) is the same as $X\sim \chi^2 (\nu)$.

Thus, for example in a case in which I have an $X\sim\Gamma(n,\frac{1}{2\theta})$, how should I work to obtain the analogous Chi-squared distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If
$Y\sim \chi_{2n}^2,$
then 
$$X = \theta Y \sim \text{Gamma}\left(n, \frac{1}{2\theta}\right).$$

Or, if $Y\sim \text{Gamma}\left(n, \frac{1}{2\theta}\right)$,
then
$$X = \frac{1}{\theta}Y\sim \chi_{2n}^2.$$

---

Note: I take $X\sim \text{Gamma}(r,\lambda)$ to mean
$$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(r)}\lambda^r x^{r-1}e^{-\lambda x}.$$

Comment: Ok, I agree with your answser! Just a clarification, have you proceeded with a "classic" one-to-one transformation to achieve that result?

Comment: Yes, you can use a one-to-one transformation since they are one-to-one over either support. I understand your question, so I just responded with the correct constants to multiply.